# Need to post large amount of data using xmlHttprequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I need to pass huge amount of data to server without page loading. I have this code:

```
var GlType = "<%=GlType %>";
var pageUrl = "SelectAccount.aspx?callback=true&AccountList=" +accountList +"&AnalysisDate="+analysisDate+"&GlType="+GlType;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
      var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {
      var xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlRequest.open("POST", pageUrl, true);
xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
xmlRequest.send(null);
```

I am have passed using query string its exceeded the maximum Length of query string. Help me on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using the POST method, you can pass data in the body.

```
xmlRequest.send("Field1=abc&Field2=def");
```

You can retrieve the data on the server, e.g. in ASP.NET:

```
if (Page.Request.Form["Field1"] == "abc") ...
```

For GET method you can only use the query string for transferring data.

Comment: How to retrive data in server please paste some code in  c sharp.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the request via post, but putting everything in the query string!

Instead, you should send the data as the body of the request (passed to the send method).

Comment: thanks for u'r reply How to get a data in server side post some code sample in c sharp

Comment: @Koen has posted a sample of how to retrieve the data.